# how to access an Output parameter in the old SQLHelper.cs class?

Tags: c#, sqlhelper

i'm currently modifying a legacy application that uses the SqlHelper class in c#. how do you access the OUTPUT value using an executedatareader?

Comment: its an old DAAB class, i believe its this one: http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `SqlParameter` object with the correct name, then check the parameter's value after calling `ExecuteDataReader`.

Comment: but wouldn't that defeat the parameter caching? i'm asking because that's what i'm doing right now.

Comment: It does not make sense to cache output parameter as such. BTW, you have to indicate parameter's direction as output.